# Vector differencing fails in QGIS (due to geometric errors)

Tags: qgis, vector, gvsig, differences

I was trying to correct the country shapefile of Uzbekistan for Gas flares:

[Input layer](http://biogeo.ucdavis.edu/data/gadm2.8/shp/UZB_adm_shp.zip) (the UZB_adm1) differenced by [this layer](http://www.ngdc.noaa.gov/eog/data/web_data/gasflares_v2/country_vectors_20090618/Flares_Uzbekistan_1.tgz).

In QGIS the result was that the overlapping regions - where the differencing should have taken place - were gone. I presumed it was due to wrong referencing of the UZB shapefile. Couldn't resolve it somehow.
After several desperate hours I went to gvSIG 2.2, did the differencing job there. And it worked like a charme.
Has anyone an Idea what was wrong in QGIS?

Comment: As mentioned in the post, I don't think the problem was due to wrong referencing, just geometric errors. Perhaps you should remove that from your title? :)

Comment: thanks a lot, that was a very thorough answer. title edited properly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you run a tool where the results are not what you expected, a good test is to use the **Check Geometry Validity** from *Vector > Geometry Tools > Check Geometry Validity*. I ran this for your Gas Flares shapefile and it returned a couple of intersection errors:

[image: Check Geometry Validity tool]

To resolve this, you can use **v.clean** from the *Processing Toolbox*, select the cleaning tool **snap** and set the Threshold to `0.01`:

[image: v.clean with snap]

In the **Advanced parameters** tab, you only need the *Cleaned* output so you can ignore the *Errors* one.

Now you should be able to use the **Difference** tool on your "UZB_adm1" layer with the "Cleaned" layer:

[image: Difference]

[image: Result]